# Javascript / Three.js is not working in https

Tags: javascript, html, http, https, three.js

I recently switched my http site to https.

Since I made this change, one of my projects no longer works.

In this random generator, the background using the Three.js library does not appear when the url is [in https](https://www.lookitsgraphic.com/projects/generator.html)

[But in http](https://www.lookitsgraphic.com/projects/generator.html) , it works beautiful and well.

Does anyone know any solution to this problem?

Thank you for your consideration in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the three.min.js file and save it on to your https server.

And instead of loading the script from http server, provide the path of your https server where you put the three.min.js file.

```
<script src="https://[path to your server]/js/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Do you think i can call Three.min.js through a link without url, like `../js/three.min.js`? 
And will that make the opening of the web page slower?

Comment: I think CDN is a better option. But both the options load file from the same hosts, either you load it without URL path or with URL path. I don't think there is much difference.

Answer (score 1):

Open your developer tools and look at the console, you'll find the explanation:

[image]

What this means is that you're not allowed to have an `https://` site that loads some content via `http://`. This is called "mixed content" and it's a security vulnerability. If you're serving a secure site, make sure all your content is using the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I saw that this was the problem, but I tried to change the href attribute destination from `src="http://[link]"` to `src="https://[link]"` or `src="//[link]"`but it does not work.

Comment: Yeah, you're placing too much trust on the file served at `brangerbriz.net`. That file has an invalid https certificate (your browser should warn you about this when [you visit the file directly](https://threejsplaygnd.brangerbriz.net/js/Detector.js)), plus that file may be modified or deleted in the future, breaking your site. You should try hosting your own files, so you're not relying on someone else's. Just copy the file to your server, or grab the [Three.js source from github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/build) and host it in your own server https://www.lookitsgraphic.com

Answer (score 1):

If your JavaScript or Three.js code is not working in an HTTPS environment, make sure that all your assets and scripts are loaded over HTTPS. Browsers block mixed content, so ensure everything is served securely.